# Primeng P-calendar issue (UTC)

Tags: angular, primeng, utc, primeng-calendar

I suffer the P-calender problem.

I choose a date (without time) from the calendar (ex. 03-09-2019)
My model updates with a date object Tue Sep 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

I send this date to the API I'm using but it works in UTC so it converts it resulting to 2019-09-02T18:30: 00.000Z.

API field is date only (no time no timezone) and it stores it as 02-09-2019 which is wrong.

Consider choosing a date from the calendar (without time) set the date in 00:00:00 in UTC time but not 00:00:00 in local time zone. Selecting a date from the browser in India Standard Time should set like 2019-09-03T18:30:00.000Z.

Comment: Can anyone help me, for this problem

Comment: if you can use momentjs, then you can simply add `const startDateUtc = moment(
    startDate,
    'DD/MM/YY',
    'Pacific/Auckland'
)
    .add(1, 'days')
    .utc()
    .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');`

Comment: The above is just an example. Keep in mind this is one way of solving your current issue. Because you belong to different time zone.

Comment: tanks for your reply @Ragavan Rajan. I 'll try to solve.

Comment: Answer :    // fOR UTC timeZone
  private fixUTCDate(date): void {
    if (date) {
      date.setTime(new Date(new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 *
        1000)).toUTCString()));
    }
  }